# For my suffix, I'm just a prey

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme, poetry

> My prefix sells some goods
>   My infix is proud
>   My suffix lurks in the woods
>   My voice can be loud
>
> In the ancient times,
>   I pave the way
>   But for my suffix,
>   I’m just a prey

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm thinking...

> Stallion

My prefix sells some goods

> stalls do that.

My infix is proud

> Tall and proud.

My suffix lurks in the woods

> Lions can, though they generally lurk other places

My voice can be loud

> It happens

In the ancient times,
I pave the way

> horses were used for many tasks, including both forging into new territories and actual roadwork

But for my suffix,
I’m just a prey

> A lion will absolutely eat a horse.

Answer (score 2):

A speculative suggestion is a

> guineafowl

My prefix sells some goods

> gui - a graphical user interface on retail websites, sells very many goods.

My infix is proud

> [neaf](http://webstersdictionary1828.com/Dictionary/neaf) - a fist - used by [Shakespeare](https://www.shakespeareswords.com/Public/Searchresults.aspx?search=neaf&WholeWordSearch=False) - and a showing a fist is a proud display.

My suffix lurks in the woods

> owl - they commonly nest in trees

My voice can be loud

> Guineafowls are notoriously noisy.

In the ancient times, I pave the way

> [Guineafowls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guineafowl) rank among the oldest of the gallinaceous birds, so paved the way for other birds.

But for my suffix, I’m just a prey

> According to one [source](https://owlcation.com/stem/The-Guinea-Fowl-Interesting-Facts-and-Information), its main predators are fox, coyotes, hawks and owls!

Answer (score 0):

> Are you **COBBLESTONE**?

My prefix sells some goods:

> We're missing the 'r' but a cobbler sells/mends shoes

My infix is proud:

> Someone who is "blest" would be proud

My suffix lurks in the woods:

> Stones are found in the woods

My voice can be loud:

> Cobblestones are loud when riding over

In the ancient times, I pave the way:

> Cobblestones pave many old cities

But for my suffix, I’m just a prey:

> A bit of a stretch, but cobblestones could be crushed / paved over by normal stones

A few points are off so I doubt it's right, but it fits a lot of them.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling, Leo! Too bad your current answer do not match well with the clues provided. Think awhile and try again sometime.

Comment: Hi Leo, good thinking! Please take OP's comment in a positive sense; we try to be as welcoming as possible, but character limits and language barriers, among other difficulties, sometimes make us sound terse. Apart from the "proud" clue and the missing r, this seems to be an excellent fit. (We'll talk about the prey thing later :-)